# Not saved tax vat field entered in checkout page in magento

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, customer-address

**Customer Address in Admin Page:**

[image]

**In my checkout page,**

[image]

**Filled  the fields and I placed the order,**

[image]

**After placed an order I checked in my backend,all the fields are saved correctly except taxvat field.**

[image]

Comment: You have selected a new address, so check the new address added, not the default one. from your last image, check the one beneath, whose street address is "third street" and no second street address

Answer (score 3):

Override core module `Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage`
In `onepage.php` file,

```
 public function saveBilling($data, $customerAddressId)
 {
```

After this,

```
 $address->implodeStreetAddress();
```

Add the line,

```
 $address->setVatId($data['taxvat']);  

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem. It is a mistake made in the template file.

Open the file \app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\customer\tab\addresses.phtml

There is the following code block (depending on version it may vary):

```
<?php
    $this->getForm()->addValues($_address->getData())
                    ->setHtmlIdPrefix("_item{$_address->getId()}")
                    ->setFieldNameSuffix('address['.$_address->getId().']');
    $this->addValuesToNamePrefixElement($_address->getPrefix())
         ->addValuesToNameSuffixElement($_address->getSuffix());
?>
```

What is needed to correct the problem is to change the call of "addValues" to "setValues". This will prevent leaving the old data in the new form by overriding the null/notset values.

So change to this:

```
<?php
    $this->getForm()->setValues($_address->getData())
                    ->setHtmlIdPrefix("_item{$_address->getId()}")
                    ->setFieldNameSuffix('address['.$_address->getId().']');
    $this->addValuesToNamePrefixElement($_address->getPrefix())
         ->addValuesToNameSuffixElement($_address->getSuffix());
?>
```